# Woocommerce get undefined cookie when calculate fees after updated_checkout fired

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

i try to make custom field (next will called "package") on woocommerce checkout page that will determine whether the extra field applied or not when the value of custom field changed. and the package field must be placed below shipping option.

my problem is to make the extra fees get applied on the changes of package. I made code below to record the changes of the package and store it in cookie then reload the page to get the woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook fired and set the selected package according to cookie value.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $( 'body' ).bind( 'updated_checkout', function() {
            $( 'select.package' ).change(function(){
                document.cookie="package="+jQuery('.package').val();
                location.reload();
            });

            if(jQuery.cookie('package')!=''){
                jQuery('select.package').val(jQuery.cookie('package'));
            }
        });
    });
```

below is my fees calculate code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;
        $discount=-5.55;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Discount-'.$_COOKIE['package'], $discount, true, 'standard' );
}
```

in code above i try to print out the cookie to check if i get the correct value or not, after the page reloaded and before updated_checkout fired i got the correct value but after updated_checkout fired i got "undefined" from cookie.
i try to post the screenshot but i need 10 reputation to do it.

you guys can try it here http://dev.puredataconsulting.com/cupcake-cms/orders/ and try to make an order of 6 regular cupcake or more to meet first condition for extra fees. Then process to checkout. on the checkout page, below shipping option you will find "Package" and then "Discount-{package cookie value}"

if i can get the correct value of the package cookie on the woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook, i can make if condition to decide when the extra fees should be applied according to the chosen package.

Thanks in advance guys, hope get help from you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2999

You may need to swap **updated_checkout** to **update_checkout**

```
$('body').bind('update_checkout', function() {
    // code
);
```